# How to unconditionally respond with a gif and a 200 with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a config that looks like this.

```
location / {
  empty_gif;
}
```

This works fine for GETs. The client receives a 200 response and an empty gif no matter what location or parameter he gives. If the client sends a POST though, this responds with a 405 and no gif.

The empty_gif module doesn't seem to accept any parameters that'd help, or at least it's not documented as such. Any suggestions for a good way get the expected behavior (responding with a 200 and a gif with *any* request)?

### Edit

To get around this, I changed my requirements. I always return a 200, but only return a gif with GETs. This is not as straight forward as it should be though. `empty_gif` isn't allowed inside `if`s.

```
location / {
  empty_gif;
  if ($request_method != GET) {
    return 200;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the nginx source at ngx_http_empty_gif_module.c:

```
 if (!(r->method & (NGX_HTTP_GET|NGX_HTTP_HEAD))) {
    return NGX_HTTP_NOT_ALLOWED;
 }
```

So it is not going to work.  If you want to, you can  remove this line and recomplile to avoid this and get what you want.  There is no other way around it.

Comment: You're right, and even more insidiously, you can't use empty_gif inside an if. I simply changed my problem and returned a 200, but with no gif in methods other than GET.